# site created using drush arr failing with missing index.php

Tags: drush

I am using drush archive to copy a live site to a test environment.  The test environment is on my local machine, the live site is on a hosted platform.

The arr command seems to complete successfully and the new database config is correctly appended to settings.php, the files are all restored to the appropriate directory on my local machine and the database is created and populated.  So far, so good.

If I navigate to the default page  `http://localhost/~drew/site2`, the home page is displayed, but it is clear that the CSS is from my theme is not available - I think that this is because the CSS was compressed and cached on the live site, so I can probably ignore that for now.  If however, I try and navigate to any other page, I get an HTTP 404 saying `localhost://~drew/site2/index.php not found` yet when I check the filesystem, it's definitely there, and the web server can clearly see it because it created the home page earlier when I navigated to the default page.

I do use pathauto and have set explicit path names for my pages on the live site - could this be broken in some way when restored?

Thanks

Comment: Update:  I think it has something to do with the way Mac OS X and apache handle the `~drew` construct.  The full path for `~drew` resolves to `/Users/drew` and that is where the `site2` directory exists.  However, machine level sites are to be found in `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and it appears that when the `~drew` gets converted to `/Users/drew`, apache then starts to look for documents in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/Users/drew`

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is likely that you need to set the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in the .htaccess file.  Edit your .htaccess, find the line that looks like

```
# RewriteBase /
```

And add a line under it that reads

```
RewriteBase /~drew/site2
```

then clear Drupal caches, and try your site.